# Как разрешить доступ к FTP на определенных страницах сайта?

Tags: ftp, php

Теперь подробнее: Меня интересует как сделать так чтобы ссылка находящаяся во flash плеере (формат flv, mp4) проигрывала только на страницах моего сайта. Пробывал обычниые методы авторизации на FTP (ftp_connect, ftp_fget, ftp_get и т.д.), но при воспроизведении вылетало окошко для авторизации на FTP и пока не авторизуешься воспроизведение не возможно, хотя соединение было успешно установлено.

Особенность: при введении ссылки в браузерную строку или любой download програмы было запрещено на скачивание, а на странице сайта во flash плеере было разрешено. Анонимного соединения нет.

Помогите реализовать мою идею. Готов заплатить за реализацию по договоренной цене. Писать на smalc2244@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

а если .htaccess

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
    #Запрещаем загрузку файлов с внешних сайтов
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?domainname.com/ [nc]
    RewriteRule .*.(flv|mp4)$ http://domainname.com/img/stop_stealing_bandwidth.gif[nc]
```

где

```
 RewriteRule .*.(mp4|flv)$ http://domainname.com/img/stop_stealing_bandwidth.gif[nc]
```

Не забудьте изменить http://domainname.com на свой домен
http://domainname.com/img/stop_stealing_bandwidth.gif - ссылка на картинку какая будет показываться на других сайтах заместь файла

Comment: http://uppod.ru/

Comment: Проверьте, если что пишите

Comment: Пробывал такой метод, но результатов не дал. Все равно требует залогинится на ftp сервере, а на файлы находящиеся на public_html работает. Данный метод уже видет в паблике, но все равно спасибо, может другим поможет)))